# TNSPING hangs after result

Tags: windows, oracle, freeze, tnsping

For some reason TNSPING totally works as expected besides one annoying aspect.
After returning a result like "OK (20ms)" it hangs for about 5 minutes.

Here's my environment:
Windows 7 64bit client, Oracle 12.1.0.2 64bit client.

It doesn't matter which DB I ping, even if I provide a not existing database name it returns an error quite immediately and hangs after that.

I've recorded a trace file already by adding TNSPING.TRACE_LEVEL = SUPPORT to SQLNET.ORA but it only contains entries till the result is shown. While it hangs nothing is logged.

Connecting to databases using sqlplus or e.g. TOAD is not a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue was resoved by removing LDAP from sqlnet.ora
see here: https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/sqlplus-tnsping-everything-just-hang-without-errors/

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (LDAP,tnsnames)
```

Comment: That could help, if it takes time **before** the ping is made. In this case the server is resolved and pinged immediately.